# SQL to return result for each value found even if duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm no SQL expert and would like to get results from a database where parameters can be duplicate.

```
SELECT refId FROM tableRefs WHERE comment LIKE "selection"; 

595
595
595
595
595
595
595
595
595
597
597
597
597
597
597
597
597
597
598
598

SELECT * from valueTable;

value1 595
value2 596
value3 597
value4 598
value5 599

SELECT value from valueTable WHERE index IN (SELECT refId FROM tableRefs WHERE comment LIKE "selection");

value1
value3
value4
```

But I need to get (for a file export)

```
value1
value1
value1
value1
value1
value1
value1
value1
value1
value3
value3
value3
value3
value3
value3
value3
value3
value3
value4
value4
```

I guess `WHERE IN` is not the right command to use here.
Do you know how I should proceed ?
Thank you very much for helping.

EDIT:
Here is the real command I would like to perform :

```
SELECT custom_name
FROM files
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT file_id
    FROM user_entries
    WHERE ref_id IN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM entries
        WHERE id IN
        (
            SELECT ref_id
            FROM user_entries
            WHERE val > 0 AND file_id IN
            (
                SELECT id
                FROM files
                WHERE cat_id = (SELECT id FROM file_categories WHERE title = 'selection')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

So it's more complex and I don't know how to "adapt" this with an `INNER JOIN` command.
Do I need intermediate table/array variable ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of using a join?  Try something like this:

```
SELECT t2.value
FROM tableRefs t1
INNER JOIN valueTable t2
    ON t1.refId = t2.`index`
WHERE t1.comment LIKE 'selection'
```

By the way, `index` is a reserved keyword in MySQL and you should avoid using it to name your columns, tables, etc.  I placed backticks around it in my query as a precaution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I understand the mechanism here but my real situation it's a bit more complicated since the query is more complex. I added the real query I'd like to perform. I may need some intermediate array ?

Comment: You should not be drastically changing your question after others have answered.  Off the top of my head, you just need a series of inner joins.

Comment: I edited your actual query and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted the real case maybe. I have changed a bit the edit. It's maybe unclear but the first 3 lines are equivalent to `SELECT value from valueTable WHERE index IN` and the rest to `SELECT value from valueTable WHERE index IN`

Comment: This parenthesis block returns (works fine) the list of indexes with duplicates from which I want to get the corresponding site_url in files table.

Comment: You need to update and show a _minimal_ sample data set for the actual problem, along with table structure and the expected output.  What you have above is sample data for a problem which does not exist, and that won't work here.

Comment: I managed to make it work with INNER JOIN (that I nevec had used before). Thanks again

Comment: @chris3389 Glad I was able to help in some way.  Next time clearly state your real problem (or a minimzed version of it) for best results.